# Database for image tagging

Tags: c#, database-design, linq-to-entities

I need to design an image tagging database for a school project.

The site will have Images, Tags and Users. Evey Image gets tagged with one or more of the tags (Tags are things like: summer, beach, Tyoko etc.), but I also need to keep track of the history of who added and removed which tags.

The solution I came up with was to have a TagHistory table like this:

```cs
public class TagHistory
{
    public virtual int TagHistoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual User TaggedBy{ get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

So the current tags on an image would simply be the images latest TagHistory entry.

This is causing problems however for searching, because only the latest TagHistory entry counts I first have to get all the current TagHistories for every image and *then* preform the filtering. This is what I came up with to search for all images containing a particular tag:

```cs
var curTagHis = from tagHistory in ctx.TagHistories
                group tagHistory by tagHistory.Image
                into groups
                select groups.OrderByDescending(th => th.Date).FirstOrDefault();

var images = from tagHistory in curTagHis 
             where tagHistory.Tags.Any(t => t.TagID == tag.TagID)
             select tagHistory.Image;
```

And I imagine it's only going to get worse as I add more features.

I was thinking that maybe I need to come up with a design that splits an images' current tags, and it's history of tags into separate entities. Would that be a good direction to go or is there some other way to do this? I'm guessing this must be a solved problem already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split it. The end user is not going to search for pictures based upon what tags the picture had 3 weeks ago, but what tags it currently has. I would go with something like this:

```
create table images
(
    id int primary key,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    file_location varchar(255) not null
);

create table tags
(
    id int primary key,
    title varchar(255) not null
);

create table images_tags
(
    image_id int not null,
    tag_id int not null,
    primary key (image_id, tag_id)
);

create table images_tags_log
(
    image_id int not null,
    tag_id int not null,
    created_by varchar(255) not null,
    date_create datetime not null,
    deleted_by varchar(255),
    date_delete datetime null,
    primary key (image_id, tag_id, date_create)
);
```

What this allows is for an easy pull of what tags an image has currently, but if you want more info you can look into the `image_tags_log` table.